# Python: to get specific element from json data

Tags: python, list

The original data is tuple

```
    data = {'trades': [{'id': '9229', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34505', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:01.767987144Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9310', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.0463', 'marginUsed': '28.1266', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9240', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:40:54.539350738Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9230', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9231', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:02.589631870Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.01000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9219', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34465', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:53.369040131Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9312', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.4618', 'marginUsed': '28.1266'}, {'id': '9216', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34454', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:41.086253690Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9355', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.5761', 'marginUsed': '28.1266', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9246', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T09:05:54.649091912Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9217', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9216', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9082', 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP', 'price': '0.83590', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:24.859730068Z', 'initialUnits': '465584', 'initialMarginRequired': '14720.1831', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '465584', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2194.7683', 'marginUsed': '14795.8871', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9083', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:25.239631861Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9082', 'price': '0.84089', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9084', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:25.572935468Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9082', 'price': '0.83313', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '8954', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price': '1.13149', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:15.383062430Z', 'initialUnits': '-465031', 'initialMarginRequired': '14702.3271', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '-462031', 'realizedPL': '-2.9616', 'closingTransactionIDs': ['9175', '9177', '9179'], 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'averageClosePrice': '1.13219', 'unrealizedPL': '1047.3621', 'marginUsed': '14682.9756', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '8955', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:16.052566962Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '8954', 'price': '1.12647', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '8956', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:16.405563212Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '8954', 'price': '1.13421', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}], 'lastTransactionID': '9257'}
([{'unrealizedPL': 2.0463, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9229, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 8, 1, 1, 767987, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 2.4618, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9219, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 53, 369040, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 2.5761, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9216, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 41, 86253, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 2194.7683, 'currentUnits': 465584, 'trade_id': 9082, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 6, 31, 24, 859730, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 1047.3621, 'currentUnits': -462031, 'trade_id': 8954, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 6, 27, 15, 383062, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}],
 True)
```

`print (data[1])` result as below:

```
{'trades': [{'id': '9229', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34505', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:01.767987144Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9310', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '1.9420', 'marginUsed': '28.1181', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9240', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:40:54.539350738Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9230', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9231', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:02.589631870Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.01000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9219', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34465', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:53.369040131Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9312', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.3574', 'marginUsed': '28.1181'}, {'id': '9216', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34454', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:41.086253690Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9355', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.4716', 'marginUsed': '28.1181', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9246', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T09:05:54.649091912Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9217', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9216', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9082', 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP', 'price': '0.83590', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:24.859730068Z', 'initialUnits': '465584', 'initialMarginRequired': '14720.1831', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '465584', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2316.8926', 'marginUsed': '14793.4660', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9083', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:25.239631861Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9082', 'price': '0.84089', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9084', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:31:25.572935468Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9082', 'price': '0.83313', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '8954', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'price': '1.13149', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:15.383062430Z', 'initialUnits': '-465031', 'initialMarginRequired': '14702.3271', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '-462031', 'realizedPL': '-2.9616', 'closingTransactionIDs': ['9175', '9177', '9179'], 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'averageClosePrice': '1.13219', 'unrealizedPL': '930.7071', 'marginUsed': '14680.5730', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '8955', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:16.052566962Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '8954', 'price': '1.12647', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '8956', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T06:27:16.405563212Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '8954', 'price': '1.13421', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}], 'lastTransactionID': '9257'}
```

How can I access the `trade_id` and `id` that contains `type:'TAKE_PROFIT'`into a list.

Comment: You data is not in correct format

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I have modified. Also, it should be `print(data[1]`.

Comment: It's not correct still. There is a tuple after the `data` dictionary which is not assign to anything

Comment: it seems like there are two parts, `trades` , `unrealizedPL` and True. The is exactly the output from the API

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
for trade in data[1]['trades']:
    if trade['type'] == 'TAKE_PROFIT':
        pass # do something with 'trade[trade_id]' and 'trade[id]'
```

Comment: `data['trades']` return `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: I have edited it, but your data object in the question does not match this.